# Change windows files permissions from Ubuntu

Tags: windows, ubuntu, permissions, ntfs

I need to change a windows file permissions from Ubuntu, I found that article about it https://askubuntu.com/questions/195464/how-to-change-file-permission-from-ubuntu-wubi-install I did change that line in the Grub and update it ... but even after doing this I still CAN'T change windows files permissions

Comment: By posting that other question, are you implying that you're using Ubuntu via Wubi as well?

Comment: No, Ubuntu is installed in its own partition !!

Comment: What's the end goal, that may change the approach.  Thanks!

Comment: [This might help](http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-advanced/ownership-and-permissions/).

Comment: What filesystem holds your files?